# softlayer CDN cname delete

Tags: api, cdn, cname, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Does somebody know a way to delete CNAME entries attached to Softlayer CDN?

We've created an object store with files published on it. We've associated the CDN to this object store and added a CNAME entry to match our domain.

This is working good. There is no trace in Softlayer console of CNAMEs.
Using the API we can list those using:

```
GET "https://$USER:$KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_ContentDelivery_Account/$ID/getOriginPullMappingInformation.xml"
```

But I don't see how to remove a CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_ContentDelivery_Account/deleteOriginPullRule

example:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_ContentDelivery_Account/$CDNID/deleteOriginPullRule

Method: Post

Payload:
{
  "parameters": ["op840414"]
}

Note: change "op840414" with the id of the CNAME you wish to send to a better life.
```

Regards